# Move Uploded file is not working, on Godaddy (but Working on localhost)

Tags: php

My Simple code is:

```
   <?php 
    if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
    {
        $t = time();
        if ($_FILES['image']['name']!="")
              { 
         $target1 = "bannerImage/".$t.$_FILES['image']['name'];
          if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$target1))
                {
                //Code is not reaching Here
                 }
               }
    }
?>
```

I don't Know why in Godaddy Server Its not working, but its fine on my localhost

Comment: What's "not working"?  What's the problem here?  Do you see an error?  Do you have permission to write to the folder?  What happens on GoDaddy?  We need more details so we can help and not just wildly guess.

Comment: Does your script have permissions to write the the `bannerImage` directory.

Comment: Sir, that Issue have been solved Now,

there was an permission issue, I have given wrong permission

Comment: @AlokJha Can you tell me how you resolved it? I am trying it since 2 days and I am unable to move the image. I am not getting any error but its not working.

Comment: Yes Sure, 
There was permission issue of file, 
Just select the folder where you want to uploaded images, and change its permission to 777

Comment: Moving files to arbitrary places based on the name provided by the user is **extremely dangerous**.

Comment: yes, 
Here name has been replaced by time() + user provider name

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the issue by giving file permission, 
It was by-default 644, I just set it to 777.

Now its looks fine for me

Answer (score 1):

Try Giving

> **Write** *permission* to the **Application Pool Group** to your **[Your Folder]**.

It can be given from:

> **Manage Hosting -> [Your Domain] -> Virtual Directories -> [Your Folder] ->  Directory Access Permissions**

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
    {
        $t = time();
        if ($_FILES['image']['name']!="")
              { 
                 $path = '/folder_name';
                 $uid = uniqid();
                 $name = basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
                 $final_path = $path."_".$uid."_"$iname;
          if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$final_path))
                {
                //Code is not reaching Here
                 }
               }
    }
?>
```

i think this script will help you

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a .htaccess file in the directory where you uploaded the files